# Meaning of "se ne devono andare"

Tags: meaning, verbs, pronouns, particles

I have trouble with the following sentence:

> Non se ne devono andare tutti?

First, I think that "se" = "si+ne", so "se" is not "if". With this, I would guess that the sentence refers to the following, probably incorrect, Italian sentence "Non si devono andare tutti ne?". That is, the meaning should be "Shouldn't they all go there?" Am I right?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Thank you, Gae. S.

Comment: Indeed, this _se_ is not that same _se_ that means “if”, but it's *not* “si+ne”. _Ne_ is a separate pronoun that happens to also appear in this sentence. _Se_ is a variant of reflexive pronoun _si_ (“Gianni si mette il cappello”) which is used in certain positions, especially before another pronoun (“Gianni se lo toglie”).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a first, informal approximation, one may think *andarsene* as a kind of “phrasal verb”, composed of a “normal” verb (*andare*) and some suitable particles (in this case, a personal pronoun followed by *ne*). So, while *andare* simply means “to go”, *andarsene* means “to go away”. Hence, as one comment mentions, the sentence *Non se ne devono andare tutti?* means “Shouldn't they all go away?”.

In some forms of the verb (infinitive, gerund) the particles are often kept in a single word at the end of the verb itself: *andarsene*, *andandosene*. In most forms (indicative, subjunctive, conditional) they are split from it and occur before it (but together; one cannot split the *se* from the *ne*): *ce ne andiamo*, *te ne andresti*.

As these examples show, you don't actually always use *se*, but rather the personal pronoun agreeing with the subject: *io me ne vado* (first person singular), *tu te ne vai* (second person singular), *lui se ne va* (third person singular) and so on.

Finally, this *se* is indeed not that same se that means “if”, but it's not “*si* + *ne*”. *Ne* is a separate pronoun that happens to also appear in this verb. *Se* is a variant of reflexive pronoun *si* (“Gianni si mette il cappello”) which is used in certain positions, especially before another pronoun (“Gianni se lo toglie”), as here. See [here](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/se3).

More technically, these verbs are in a category called *verbi pronominali*; see [here](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-pronominali_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/) for more.

Comment: Precisamente, "andarsene" è un verbo pronominale procomplementare.