# "Ne" in "se ne stava"

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, verbs, sentences, particles

I read the sentence

> Se ne stava penzoloni sull'albero.

Is "ne" mandatory here and what does it adds? Couldn't we just say

> Stava penzoloni sull'albero.

Or

> Se stava penzoloni sull'albero.

How would the corresponding question look like?

> Come se ne stave sull'albero ?

> Come stava sull'albero ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both

> Se ne stava penzoloni sull'albero.

and

> Stava penzoloni sull'albero.

are perfectly good Italian sentences, with very similar meanings. Using *starsene* (or, quite uncommonly, *starsi* and hence “Si stava ... sull'albero”), with respect to just *stare*, is done “per maggiore efficacia e per sottolineare l’idea dell’immobilità o della permanenza in una condizione” (“for greater emphasis and to stress the idea of immobility or permanence in a condition”, [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stare/), 12).

The corresponding questions would be:

> Come se ne stava sull'albero?

(no space in Italian before the question mark) and

> Come stava sull'albero?

As to the grammar of a verb such as *starsene*, it's a *verbo pronominale*, and so it behaves exactly like *andarsene*: see [my answer about the latter](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/13935/meaning-of-se-ne-devono-andare/13938#13938).