# "la" in "la finisca di chiedermela"

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, sentences

Given the sentence

> Ti comprerò una bicicletta nuova purché tu la finisca di chiedermela.

what does "la" in "la finisca di chiedermela" refers to and is it mandatory, can we say

> Ti comprerò una bicicletta nuova purché tu finisca di chiedermela.

and does it have exactly the same meaning?

Comment: _Finirla_ is still another example of a “verbo pronominale”, which I mentioned in my [answer here](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/13938/37).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this circumstance, "la" is an indeterminate pronoun and it implicitly refers to something negative.

Both those sentences are grammatically correct, but I would argue that they have slightly different meanings.

- `finirla` = "Troncare, far cessare, smettere", "a proposito di liti, contrasti, questioni noiose e sim." ([Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/finire/), definition `e.`). You may specify `di + <infinito>` but it can also stand alone. This sounds like actively putting an end *to* a negative action to me.
- `finire di + <infinito>` = "Giungere al termine di" (definition `d.`). This sounds more neutral to me, as if it's reaching the natural end *of* an action.

A personal note - both sentences are rather odd: of course someone would stop asking for something once they receive it; so the conditional clause, as it stands, is meaningless. It would make more sense if it were `Ti comprerò una bicicletta nuova purché tu la finisca di importunarmi`.

Comment: I wouldn't say that “"la" is an indeterminate pronoun and it implicitly refers to something negative”. It's the pronominal verb _finirla_ that, as you correctly say, is used about quarrels, requests and so on, but _la_ doesn't have here a specific function as a pronoun referring to something.

Comment: The Treccani reference I linked says "*finirla*, con il pron. *la* indeterminato".

Comment: Exactly, Andrea, *indeterminato*, that is, it doesn't refer to anything in particular. It's just how pronominal verbs work in Italian. Just think about _piantarla_: “Piantala e vieni qui”. Would you say that “-la” refers to something?

Comment: That's why I specified with "implicitly". And IMO "-la" in "piantala" has the exact same role. I hypothesise that originally, these "la" were explicitly referring to something negative: "finisci questa <cosa sgradevole>" > "finiscila". But that's just my uneducated opinion.

Comment: I agree that, in some remote etymological time, pronouns such as *-la* in these verbs referred to something, but in present-day Italian they simply don't. Just think about a sentence such as _piantala di dire fesserie_: how would we make it explicit? what should be “planted”? Or, as in your example: _finiscila di piangere_ = * _finisci questa cosa di piangere_? Those are _verbi pronominali_ and the vestigial pronoun is just this.

Answer (score 1):

The sentences have the same meaning but the first one sounds better. In this case "la" does not refer to a noun and is not mandatory. With "la finisca" and in general "finirla" you ask to end something annoying that has been going on for a long time (for example in this one what is probably a child has bored an adult for a long time so that he bought them a bike). With "finirla" you highlight the fact that the person has bored you and therefore the request is more imperative. Another example:

> Vuoi finirla di annoiarmi?